# fix bottom footer to bottom on entering data to ion-input

Tags: css, ionic2

I have a page if its native storage is empty a div arises, that div has input field when i try to enter data to that ion-input keyboard pushes up along with the footer bar.

```
<ion-content>
   <div>...........</div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer class="bottom_bar">
    <ion-row > <ion-col> ....</ion-col><ion-row>
    <ion-row > <ion-col> ....</ion-col><ion-row>
</ion-footer>
```

in my css

```
.bottom_bar
    {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 2vh;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below default classes

```
  <ion-content>
    <button fab fab-left fab-bottom danger fab-fixed>
  <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
</button>

<ion-fixed class="fixed-div">
<button fab fab-right fab-bottom dark>
  <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
</button>
</ion-fixed>
```

```
<style>
.fixed-div {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Actually i need my input to get scrolled up on entering date, the keypad comes and hides the input @Dhaarani